# Acceso a controlador en CodeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter

Tengo una consulta en `CodeIgniter`, tengo un controlador con el cual hago trabajos específicos y no quiero que a el se tenga acceso a través de la `url`, ejemplo,

```
http://miproyecto/tareas/index
```

Que solo muestre sus datos en un `layout` central que tengo implementado, como debería hacerlo, creo y no estoy seguro que la solución esta en el archivo `Routes`, alguna sugerencia ? .

Comment: una solución es como te comenta @Pedro Garcias, y hasta abajo del archivo **routes.php** poner un genérico para las rutas que no reconozcas que las mande a un controlador o a error ´$route['(.+)'] = 'custom_error'´ (pero tendrías que meter aquí todas tus url´s para ser mapeadas). Otra es hacer private cada función que no quieras que se acceda por url a esa función especifica

Answer (score 0):

Puedes trabajar con Rutas relativas, esto se hace en el archivo config/routes.php

en el archivo puedes configurar la ruta como tu deseas

```
$route['NombreQueQuieras']              = 'tareas';
$route['NombreQueQuieras']              = 'tareas/funcion2';
```

Con esa sencilla ruta, le estamos diciendo a codeigniter que tenemos un controlador llamado tareas, y dentro un método llamado funcion2. con esto puedes hacer distinto llamado a metodos dentro de tu controlador